# bunch of histograms next to each other

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

In [this](http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140806063515361458.png) figure, in the 1st plot, the grid divides the plot in "windows" and each window is divided in subwindows (made with let's say 5 data).
Then the slope of each subwindow is calculated and saved.
Next I divide the polar plane in 16 quadrants and calculate which quadrant correspond to each slope. So, I get something like this:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4
4,1,-1,-2,...
```

In the dataset above, each number is the quadrant that represents the slope of a subwindow and each row represents a window (The histograms are calculated with this dataset).

What I'm looking for is that the figure at the top, the 2nd plot shows the histogram of each window under its corresponding window.
All I could get is [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html)  from the matplotlib page but none of those examples are close to what I need because I need the histograms next to each other without blocking each other.
Sometimes, depending on the parameters used, it could be more than 800 histograms in the same plot.

Comment: Could you please clarify where do you want which subplot and especially if you want some plots spanning multiple rows or columns?

Comment: Sure, the figure above has two subplots divided by a vetical grid in which would be windows, the first one has a normal plot (x,y), the second one is empty because a row of histograms (the histogram of each window, under its corresponding window) must be there. PD: I'm learning english so if I made a mistake please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140807123901827897.jpg) is an example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: So you want multiple histograms in one plot side-by-side, all sharing the same x- and y-axis?

Comment: Yes, side-by-side. Is this possible with matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can display multiple plots side-by-side below a larger one using [Gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some data
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
y = np.sin(x)

# plot it
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax0 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (0, 0), colspan=4)
ax0.plot(x, y)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (1, 0))
ax1.hist(y)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (1, 1))
ax2.hist(y)
ax2.set_yticklabels([])
ax2.set_yticks([])
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (1, 2))
ax3.hist(y)
ax3.set_yticklabels([])
ax3.set_yticks([])
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (1, 3))
ax4.hist(y)
ax4.set_yticklabels([])
ax4.set_yticks([])

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0) # no space left between hists in 2nd row
```

Results in:
[image]